# Why can't I specify both a Primary Key and a Unique Constraint on the same table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, primary-key, unique-constraint

I'm trying to create a table:

```
CREATE TABLE [MyTable]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY,
    [Column1] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Column2] [int] NOT NULL

    CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable_Id] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
    CONSTRAINT [UQ_MyTable_Column1_Column2] UNIQUE ([Column1], [Column2])
)
```

This script fails with the error:

> Both a PRIMARY KEY and UNIQUE constraint have been defined for column
> 'Column2', table 'MyTable'. Only one is allowed.

Why is this restriction enforced? How can I create a table with these properties?

Comment: I disagree with the vote to close.  In any event, it's been answered.

Comment: I could perfectly reproduce the typo problem, which was the original cause of the problem at hand. Voted to reopen.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You missed a comma after the primary key constraint.

```
CREATE TABLE [MyTable]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY,
    [Column1] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Column2] [int] NOT NULL

    CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable_Id] PRIMARY KEY ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [UQ_MyTable_Column1_Column2] UNIQUE ([Column1], [Column2])
)
```

Comment: Missing this comma might be a common thing .. The message issued is not very clear I am thinking.  Good to have this Stack Overflow Q and A as a reference and pointer in how to resolve.

Answer (score 3):

```
CREATE TABLE [MyTable]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY,
    [Column1] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Column2] [int] NOT NULL

    CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable_Id] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])

)

  ALTER TABLE [MyTable] ADD CONSTRAINT [UQ_MyTable_Column1_Column2] UNIQUE ([Column1], [Column2])
```

Comment: Why does this work and what I wrote originally doesn't?

Comment: I guess the other answers give a hint to why that is. Syntax errors can lead to very misleading error messages :(

Answer (score 2):

Or put a comma between the primary key declaration and unique constraint declaration:

```
CREATE TABLE [MyTable]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY,
    [Column1] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Column2] [int] NOT NULL

    CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable_Id] PRIMARY KEY ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [UQ_MyTable_Column1_Column2] UNIQUE ([Column1], [Column2])
)
```